# What causes System Idle Process to run down my CPU so much

Tags: windows-7, cpu, cpu-usage, task-manager

I noticed my laptop was being a bit unresponsive so I checked the processes tab and found that `System Idle Process` is using nearly all of my CPU power.

[image]

Why is this happening and how do I stop it?

Comment: Did you try reading the description?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yes I did, but I didn't figure it would display that in the CPU tab.

Answer (score 2):

The system idle process indicates the time the system is idle. It's not using your CPU power but indicating that it's not used.